# Rails association user & contacts throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, psql

Amended the code base in 'contacts controller' from `@contacts = Contact.all` to `@contacts = current_user.contact` so a user can see only their contacts (currently any user sees all the contacts) This is throwing the below error. Tried tweaking but still no success and have checked the database in psql and both have id column. Any ideas or amendment needed in the code?

`Failure/Error: <% if @contacts.any? %> ActionView::Template::Error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column contacts.user_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" ... ^ : SELECT 1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1`

Contacts Controller
    class ContactsController < ApplicationController

```
  before_action :contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]   before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @contacts = current_user.contact   end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new   end

  def create
    Contact.create(contact_params)
    redirect_to '/contacts'   end

  def show   end

  def edit   end

  def update
    @contact.update(contact_params)
    redirect_to '/contacts/' + "#{@contact[:id]}"   end


  def destroy
    @contact.destroy
    redirect_to '/contacts'   end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :surname, :email, :phone, :image)   end

  def contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])   end


end
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

end
```

Contact model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :image, styles: {thumb: "100x100>"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Index html

```
<%if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<%end%>

<% if @contacts.any? %>
  <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(contact.image.url(:thumb)), contact_path(contact) %>
  <h3><%= contact.firstname%> <%=contact.surname%></h3>
  <%=contact.email%><br />
  <%=contact.phone%>
  <br />
  <br />
  <%end%>
<%else%>
  No contacts yet!
<%end%>
<br />
<br />
<%= link_to 'Add a contact', new_contact_path%>
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160504125849) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "surname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Comment: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column contacts.user_id does not exist` - The error is clear enough! you have not added `user_id` foreign key to `contacts` table

Comment: "The error is clear enough!" is totally unnecessary. Often what has one person stumped is clear to another person. That's why we ask questions. :P

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do not have the `user_id` in the contacts table. That is the foreign key which is used to define a relation to the users. Add the column and then when you create the contact, add the user's id to the `user_id` column in the contacts table. Then that should work.

Comment: Have added the extra user_id column to contacts with foreign key. Now no contacts show at all in the Index view, it does load the contacts url but doesn't show any contacts, only the log out or add contact links. I cant see why . Do you have any ideas?                                                                            (Re-ran migration and and started server & db again)

Comment: It is because, you have user_id column nil for old records.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta  Why would it be nil if a new user has been created (after all amendments and restarted server&db) and new contacts added under that user? Even after all this the index just shows blank.

Comment: I told about old records not new one, replace Contact.create(contact_params) to current_user.contacts.create(contact_params)

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta Tks for the revert, thats has resolved it.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Sorry blastoff. Was busy so couldn't continue with that.